# Strange firefox bug triggers on reload

Tags: http, firefox

I noticed a bug in an old version of firefox, that was shipped with my os.

These were the sympthoms:
Guile web server failed to serve the request when data was reposted.

I came up with a minimal example to show the problem.
Steps to reproduce:

1. start the server script
2. load localhost:8080
3. select the test.csv file for upload, and upload it
4. hit the refresh button in the browser
5. answer yes to resend post data dialog.

test.scm:

```
(use-modules (web server)
             (rnrs bytevectors))

(define (handler request body)
  (if body
      (display (utf8->string body)))
  (values '((content-type . (text/html)))
          (string-append "<html><body>"
                         "<form action=\"do\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-dat\
a\">"
                         "<input type=\"file\" name=\"x\">"
                         "<input type=\"submit\">")))

(run-server handler)
```

test.csv:

```
a,b
```

Expected result: no error displayed on the console.
Actual result:

```
-----------------------------18912432064747206221264673165
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
    841:4  4 (with-throw-handler _ _ _)
In web/server/http.scm:
   127:28  3 (_)
In web/request.scm:
   205:31  2 (read-request #<closed: file 5559bbcb82a0> _)
In web/http.scm:
   1141:6  1 (read-request-line _)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
   752:25  0 (dispatch-exception _ _ _)
Bad request: Bad Request-Line: "a,b"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Some additional information:
on a whireshark capture it turns out, that the following is sent on resend:

```
POST /do HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/do
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------121791188820701943592108452984
Content-Length: 150
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0

-----------------------------121791188820701943592108452984
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

POST /do HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/do
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------121791188820701943592108452984
Content-Length: 150
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0

-----------------------------121791188820701943592108452984
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

a,b

-----------------------------121791188820701943592108452984--
```

I will check the http spec if it has anything to say about this. The first http request is partial, followed by a well formed request.

UPDATE:
It turned out that guile webserver threw the error completely legitimately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

This is actually this firfox bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434553

Fixed in firefox62.